# Vue.js vuex state not working correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using Vuex in my project with vue.js 2.0. My `app.js` looks like this:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Login from './components/Login.vue';
import Home from './components/Home.vue';
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import store from './store';

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VModal);
Vue.use(Vuex);


window.Bus = new Vue();

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Login, name: 'login' },
    { path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'home', beforeEnter: requireAuth },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
});

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store
}).$mount('#app');

function requireAuth() {
    return this.$store.state.isLoggedIn;
}
```

My `store` looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const LOGIN = "LOGIN";
const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
const LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";

const store = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
            user: null
        },
        mutations: {
            [LOGIN] (state) {
                state.pending = true;
            },
            [LOGIN_SUCCESS] (state) {
                state.isLoggedIn = true;
                state.pending = false;
            },
            [LOGOUT](state) {
                state.isLoggedIn = false;
            }
        },

        actions: {
            login({state, commit, rootState}) {
                commit(LOGIN_SUCCESS);
            },

            setUser({state, commit, rootState}, user) {
                //todo
            }
        }
    });
}

export default store;
```

However when I try to access a value from the state in my requireAuth function:

```
return this.$store.state.isLoggedIn;

or


return this.store.state.isLoggedIn;
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot read property '$store' of undefined
```

What could be wrong here?

--EDIT--

When I `console.log(store);` I see:

```
store() {
    var _mutations;

    return new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_vuex__["a" /* default */].Store({
        state: {
            isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
```

Comment: Can you console.log just imported `store` in your middleware function, what's the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the function declared in the global scope like this:

```
function requireAuth() { 
    return this.$store.state.isLoggedIn; 
}
```

So when you call this function `this` is  bound by default to `global` object. But since ES6 `this` will be `undefined` instead of the `global` object. So you get the error cannot read  `$store` of  `undefined`

Since you are importing the `store` in `app.js` you can directly use:

```
function requireAuth() { 
    return store.state.isLoggedIn; 
}
```

**EDIT**

export the created `store` instance itself, not a function that returns a `store` instance as follows:

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const LOGIN = "LOGIN";
const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
const LOGOUT = "LOGOUT";

const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
            user: null
        },
        mutations: {
            [LOGIN] (state) {
                state.pending = true;
            },
            [LOGIN_SUCCESS] (state) {
                state.isLoggedIn = true;
                state.pending = false;
            },
            [LOGOUT](state) {
                state.isLoggedIn = false;
            }
        },

        actions: {
            login({state, commit, rootState}) {
                commit(LOGIN_SUCCESS);
            },

            setUser({state, commit, rootState}, user) {
                //todo
            }
        }
    });


export default store;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I do that I still get: `Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined` when I `console.log(store);`I see: (please see edit in my question)

Answer (score 1):

The `requireAuth` function should be:

```
function requireAuth() {
    return store.state.isLoggedIn;
}
```

`requireAuth` is just a function defined in your `app.js` and `this.$store` is how you would refer to the store *inside a Vue method*. Instead, you can just refer to it in the function as `store`.